# Action checkable property hidden by QIcon

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

```
class window21(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window21,self).__init__()
        self.newAction=QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(":/im/new.png"),"&New",self,checkable=True)
        self.openAction=QtWidgets.QAction("&Open",self,checkable=True)
        self.printAction=QtWidgets.QAction("&Print",self,checkable=True)
#        self.quitAction=QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(":/im/quit.png"),"&Quit",self,checkable=True)
#        self.saveAction=QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon(":/im/save.png"),"&Save",self,checkable=True)
        self.quitAction=QtWidgets.QAction("&Quit",self,checkable=True)
        self.saveAction=QtWidgets.QAction("&Save",self,checkable=True)

        self.groupMenu=QtWidgets.QMenu("nested menu",self)
        self.groupAction=QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self)



        myMenu=self.menuBar()
        file=myMenu.addMenu("&File")
        file.addAction(self.newAction)
        file.addAction(self.openAction)
        file.addAction(self.printAction)
#        file.addAction(actions[0])

        self.groupAction.addAction(self.quitAction)
        self.groupAction.addAction(self.saveAction)


        self.groupAction.setExclusive(True)

        for j in self.groupAction.actions():
            j.setCheckable(True)
            self.groupMenu.addAction(j)

        try:
            file.addMenu(self.groupMenu)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)

        self.show()

app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ex=window21()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was creating a simple menu and learning about checkable property.Initially all my actions were having QIcon attached to them.So when I set checkable property to them I was not able to see the results.Since I wasn't able to see that it was really working or not.After some experiments I find out that QIcon hides the check and thus cant be seen.So I am thinking of is it posdible to show Icon as well as the check to the right

Comment: The icon itself is checkable (like a flat button), so there's no need to add anything else.

Comment: @ekhumoro oh yes you are right.It was hard to notice though :p